# Displaying html content to random users in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to enable the input element of my web form for users with a certain id in php, currently here is the dynamic html content:

```
<input type="text" name="you" placeholder="only user with the following id can see this, sorry." disabled>
```

Here is the code that will activate for only the chosen user:

```
 function chkboxClick(chkbox) {
        chkbox.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = !chkbox.checked;
    } // Checkbox appears asking user to check to enable input
```

I'm not specifically choosing a user, I'm trying to choose a random user. Basically there is a table in the database or some form of code which randomly selects a user and assigns the "YoureTheOne" id to that activating the above code. How do I create this table/code which randomly assigns the id to a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put **id** of that user for that you want to show ***textarea***

suppose

```
$array_id = [12,14,15,18,19,22,25];

if(in_array($current_user_id,$array_id)){
    <input type="text" name="you" value="your text">
} else {
    <input type="text" name="you" placeholder="only user with the following id can see this, sorry." disabled>
}
```

Comment: Also is the array_id a list of possible id's I could assign to a current user, why can't it just be '= [12]' or even '= [YoureTheOne]'? How does this code choose a random user from the database?